# Binding key in tmux without prefix key

Tags: tmux

I have the following in my tmux.conf

```
# Ctrl - t or t new window
unbind t
unbind C-t
bind-key t new-window
bind-key C-t new-window
```

But these commands just work if I prefix them with my leader key. How can I bind keys in tmux without need to use the leader key before?

Comment: ... how would you type a `t` as start of a command? You need the prefix to tell `tmux` to listen to the next keystroke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man tmux`:

> bind-key [-nr] [-N note] [-T key-table] key command [arguments]
> Bind key key to command.  Keys are bound in a key table.  By default (without -T), the key is bound in the prefix
> key table.  This table is used for keys pressed after the prefix key (for example, by default 'c' is bound to
> new-window in the prefix table, so 'C-b c' creates a new window).  **The root table is used for keys pressed with-
> out the prefix key: binding 'c' to new-window in the root table (not recommended) means a plain 'c' will create a
> new window.  -n is an alias for -T root.**  Keys may also be bound in custom key tables and the switch-client -T
> command used to switch to them from a key binding.  The -r flag indicates this key may repeat, see the
> repeat-time option.  -N attaches a note to the key (shown with list-keys -N).

TL;DR: `bind-key -n C-t new-window`